# Inconsistency with 2D array and for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, console.log

The following code results in the console printing "Z".

```
<script>
var x = new Array(new Array());
x[0][0] = "Z";
console.log(x[0][0]);
</script>
```

But if I replace x[0][0] = "Z" with a nested for loop of arbitrary dimensions ...

```
<script>
var x = new Array(new Array());
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        x[i][j] = "Z";
    }
}
console.log(x[0][0]);
</script>
```

... it gets stuck on the very zeroth iteration, despite that being the same instruction (as far as I see) as given in the first one. According to both Chrome and Firefox output, it suddenly considers x[0][0] to be undefined.

What's the deal?

Comment: I think the first iteration is fine, but `x[1][0]` will throw an error, since your outer array only has one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have 2D arrays. What you can do is create an **array of arrays**. In your example you did exactly that, you created an array which contains another array.

```
var x = new Array(new Array());
console.log(x.length); // 1
console.log(x[0]); // []
```

`x` is an array with one element which happens to be an array. If you are trying to access `x[1]`, i.e. the second element in the array, you will get an error because such element does not exist:

```
console.log(x[1]); // undefined
```

What you have to do is assign an array to the `i`th position in the outer array first:

```
var x = []; // create outer array
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    x[i] = []; // create inner array at i
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        x[i][j] = "Z";
    }
}
console.log(x[0][0]);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I knew it was really an array of arrays, but I wasn't properly understanding the ways that made it fundamentally different from a regular array.